# useState is not working properly in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, expo

I'm working on an application and using WordPress API for showing posts. I've created 2 buttons to navigate the list of posts. As you know there is an argument "page=" to get posts on a specific page, I've initialized a state to maintain page number. The main problem is that it's not incrementing correctly.

Post Screen Code -

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, FlatList, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { Colors } from "../constant/colors";
import globalStyles from "../constant/globalStyle";
import axios from "axios";
import PostCard from "../components/PostCard";
import CustomButton from "../components/Button";

const Updates = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://bachrasouthpanchayat.in/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?embed=true&page=${page}`
    );
    setData(response.data);
    setLoaded(true);
  };

  const previousHandler = () => {
    setLoaded(false);
    let newPage = page - 1;
    setPage(newPage);
    fetchData();
  };

  const nextHandler = () => {
    setLoaded(false);
    let newPage = page + 1;
    setPage(newPage);
    fetchData();
  };

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        ...globalStyles.container,
        backgroundColor: Colors.BACKGROUND_SCREEN,
      }}
    >
      {loaded ? (
        <>
          <FlatList
            style={{ flex: 1, margin: 10 }}
            data={data}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            renderItem={({ item }) => {
              return (
                <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.7}>
                  <PostCard
                    title={item.title.rendered}
                    imageUrl={item.jetpack_featured_media_url}
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              );
            }}
          />
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: "row",
              alignItems: "center",
              alignContent: "stretch",
              justifyContent: "center",
            }}
          >
            {page == 1 ? (
              <TouchableOpacity
                activeOpacity={0.7}
                style={{ width: "100%" }}
                onPress={nextHandler}
              >
                <CustomButton>Next</CustomButton>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ) : (
              <>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  activeOpacity={0.7}
                  style={{ marginRight: 2, width: "50%" }}
                  onPress={previousHandler}
                >
                  <CustomButton>Previous</CustomButton>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  activeOpacity={0.7}
                  style={{ width: "50%" }}
                  onPress={nextHandler}
                >
                  <CustomButton>Next</CustomButton>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </>
            )}
          </View>
        </>
      ) : null}
    </View>
  );
};

export default Updates;
```

I had logged state in every state and found that was not incrementing from 1 to 2 on pressing the button the first time. I think state updated after API call because both buttons had started showing even I've used condition to show both buttons only if the state is not 1
Please let me know if i've made any silly mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

The last argument to `useEffect` is an array of dependencies so that React will only re-run the effect when the dependencies have changed. You are passing an empty array, which tells React that there are no dependencies and the effect should only be run once, when the component is first mounted.

Now you actually want the effect to re-run when the page changes, so you should put `page` in the depenency array:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [page]);
```

---

And (credit: @Keith) you should remove the extra `fetchData()` calls in the `nextHandler` and `previousHandler`

Comment: I would also advice the OP to remove the fetchData in the nextHandler & previousHandler, otherwise it's going to do a pointless fetch of the current page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement it like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
 const fetchData = async () => {
setLoaded(true);
    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://bachrasouthpanchayat.in/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?embed=true&page=${page}`
    );
    setData(response.data);
    setLoaded(false);
  };
    fetchData();
  }, [page]);



  const previousHandler = () => {
    setPage(prevPage => prevPage - 1);
  };
```

This way whenever the user changes the page, it will automatically call the function in useEffect, since it is in the dependency array.